# Given a word vector get the word of it in word2vec

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding, doc2vec

I obtain word vectors from my code. e.g.,

```
array([ -3.09521449e-04,   2.73033947e-06,   2.15601496e-04, ...,
         5.12349070e-04,   5.04256517e-04,   8.16784304e-05], dtype=float32)
```

Now, I want to identify what is the word that represents this word vector in wor2vec genism.

I tried it using the below code. However it did not work.

```
print(model.wv.index2word(kmeans_clustering.cluster_centers_))
```

Please help me.

Comment: Given a new word, you may infer vectors, but I don't think you can reverse that...

Comment: Which word2vec implementation are you using? Regardless, the basic function should be finding similar vectors in a database. Pick the one that is most similar, probably with a distance of 0, and pick the word that comes with that most similar vector.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel I am using Gensim. I know how to get similar words using `most_similar`. But how can we do it using word vectors? Can you please tell me?

Comment: honestly I don't know, sorry. I'd need to search the API for the correct command. `n_similarity` takes docvecs as input, which might be correct, but I don't know if a docvec is the same things as a word vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gensim `most_similar()` method will take a vector as an argument, as well, but you have to explicitly supply it as one item inside a list of `positive` examples – so that it's not misunderstood as a something else.

For example:

```
wv = model.wv.['book']
similars = model.wv.most_similar(positive=[wv,])
```

Naturally, 'book' will be at the top of this list of words most-similar to its own vector.